# HDF5 error from MEEP on Ubuntu

Tags: hdf5, meep

I have installed MEEP, everything is running fine however when I try to run [this tutorial code](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Meep_Tutorial) for the straight waveguide I get the following  message:

```
-----------
Initializing structure...
Working in 2D dimensions.
Computational cell is 16 x 8 x 0 with resolution 10
     block, center = (0,0,0)
          size (1e+20,1,1e+20)
          axes (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)
          dielectric constant epsilon diagonal = (12,12,12)
time for set_epsilon = 0.0840669 s
-----------
creating output file "./eps-000000.00.h5"...
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.4) thread 3078944464:
  #000: ../../../src/H5F.c line 1430 in H5Fcreate(): unable to create file
    major: File accessability
    minor: Unable to open file
  #001: ../../../src/H5F.c line 1220 in H5F_open(): unable to open file
    major: File accessability
    minor: Unable to open file
  #002: ../../../src/H5FD.c line 1079 in H5FD_open(): open failed
    major: Virtual File Layer
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #003: ../../../src/H5FDsec2.c line 365 in H5FD_sec2_open(): unable to open file
    major: File accessability
    minor: Unable to open file
  #004: ../../../src/H5FDsec2.c line 365 in H5FD_sec2_open(): Permission denied
    major: Internal error (too specific to document in detail)
    minor: System error message
meep: error on line 450 of ../../../src/h5file.cpp: error opening HDF5 output file
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a permission error. Do you have write permission in the current directory? Or does the file `./eps-000000.00.h5` already exists and cannot be overwritten?